# storing a substr into another variable for further assignments

Tags: c++, string, stl

I have a text like this

**Student = 321321**

**Name = Jennifer Lawrence**

**course = PR**

**Phone Number = 790-3233**

I want to store only the data after the equal sign into `student->id`, `student->name`, `student->course`, `student->phone_no`

```
Student *student[100];
string  str, line;
char * temp;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fileName);

if (!inFile.is_open())
    return false;
else
{
    for(int i=0; i<100;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; getline(inFile, line) && j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (line.compare(0, 7, "Student") == 0)
            {                   
                size_t pos = line.find("=");
                temp = line.substr(pos + 2);
                strcpy(student[i]->id, temp);
            }
            else if (line.compare(0, 4, "Name") == 0)
            {
                size_t pos = line.find("=");
                temp = line.substr(pos + 2);
                strcpy(student[i]->name, temp);
            }
            else if (line.compare(0, 6, "course") == 0)
            {                   
                size_t pos = line.find("=");
                temp = line.substr(pos + 2);
                strncpy(student[i]->course, temp);
            }
            else if (line.compare(0, 5, "Phone") == 0)
            {                   
                size_t pos = line.find("=");
                temp = line.substr(pos + 2);
                strcpy(student[i]->phone_no, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The error occurs on `temp = line.substr(pos + 2);` line 
where it says:

`no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" to "char *" exists"`

Comment: Put error messages in your question, not in pictures. Also create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry, i've edited it, please check it

Comment: Please add the definition of `Student`. Better still, turn this into a [mcve].

Comment: Just use `std::string`. `char*` is a c-ism which you should avoid if possible.

Comment: Warning: `Student *student[100];` is an array of 100 pointer s to `Student`. At no point do you allocate any `Student`s. Consider replacing this with `Student student[100];` or `std::vector<Student> student;` and use the `push_back` or `emplace_back` methods to fill up the `vector`.

Comment: but when i use Student student[100], student[i]->id shows an error that says "expression must have a pointer type", sorrry im still new to programming

Comment: @BrianLee use `->` for pointers. Use `.` when it's not, so it should become `student[i].id`

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::substr()` returns a `std::string`, not a `char*`.  You can use `std::string::c_str()` to get a `const char*` needed by `strcpy` without bothering with temp:

```
strcpy(student[i]->id, line.substr(pos + 2).c_str());
```

Though, I don't see where you've allocated storage for `Student::id` is it an array? Even if you have allocated storage, you never check that you have enough. Rather than doing that, I strongly suggest making `Student::id` a `std::string` as well, then it's easy:

```
student[i]->id = line.substr(pos + 2);
```

Comment: i tried to use strcpy_s(student[i]->phone_no, line.substr(pos + 2).c_str()) and run time error occurs where i have to click break to stop it

Comment: @BrianLee Looking at your update, you have other bugs not related to your question. you've create an array of 100 Student *pointers*. You haven't created any Student objects at all.